# Is it possible to export ZF2 ACL rules?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, authorization, acl

I'm experimenting with ZF2's ACL implementation ([Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/namespaces/Zend.Permissions.Acl.html)) and can't help but think of how much unnecessary overhead there is in dynamically creating my ACL rules with each page load.  I'm not using this in a ZF2 application, just a procedural page, so no [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize) or the sort.

Is there a way to export the ACL rules so I can essentially just run a script which re-creates the ACL only when certain actions occur (IE: when a new user is created or permissions/associations are changed)?  There is an old old post which mentions this method for [ZF1](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Acl-resource-hierarchy-td676387.html), so I was wondering if there is similar ability in ZF2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was thinking about this in the wrong way.  Instead of comparing the user to the entire ACL list, I needed to compare the resource the user is requesting to the user's specific ACL list.  This way I don't have to load every user and resource in the system on every page load, only the ones which apply (IE: the current user).